# How to know the OperationContract was called by request using debug diagnostic tool

Tags: c#, iis, debugdiag, debug-diagnostic-tool

I have been monitoring the working process in IIS server, in current requests in application pools
it show request that taking time elapsed (more than 100sec). For example
url Service/RequestService time elapse 100000

because the url above is url of wcf service and there are many operation contract
such as GetRequest(), GetRequests(), CreateRequest() and more

I would like to know what operation contract was called by the request but IIS request monitor not show
any details.

My question is how I can know what operation contract in service was called using debug diagnostic tool.
I try to use debug diagnostic tool to dump and generate analysis report and there are a lot of things in there and I am not sure what the information I looking for.

Comment: Manual analysis with tools like WinDbg is required.

Comment: you could try to use the [network monitor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865), it can capture the request and look into the request body. check this document to activate message logging in WCF: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/configuring-message-logging

Comment: I try using WinDbg. I attach process id of w3wp.exe and I run command load sos.dll after that I run !runaway and looking for long running theard and then run command ~5s when 5 is thread id and then I run !clrstack and I can get operation contract name after all of above when stop debug w3wp.exe process will disappear and when in debugging the web will hang

Comment: windbg capture dump causes some performance issues because it's too heavy. you could use the WCF looging or network monitor for troubleshooting as mentioned in the above comment. WinDbg can be used for debugging kernel-mode memory dumps

Comment: @JalpaPanchal now I try to use WCF logging by add system.diagnostics in web.config of web service and open it with Microsoft trace viewer but I'm not sure the service that execute but still waiting that I'm looking for  is the same as Activity Execute with level start without stop or not ?